# Error to install libpcre3-dev on ubuntu 14.4

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I want to install libpcre3-dev on ubuntu 14.4,but when i typing this command `sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev` in got a error like below :

```
 Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
 requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
 distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
 or been moved out of Incoming.
 The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libpcre3-dev : Depends: libpcre3 (= 1:8.31-2ubuntu2) but 1:8.31-2ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: please help me friends

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/813788/cant-install-libpcre3-dev/813797

```
sudo apt-get install libpcre3=1:8.31-2ubuntu2 libpcre3-dev=1:8.31-2ubuntu2
```

Forces the correct version.